# What is the difference between los contornos and los alrededores?

Tags: sinónimos

These two nouns seem synonymous for "the outskirts" or "the surrounding areas", but I have no idea when I would choose one over the other. Are there any nuanced differences?

Comment: They are not synonymous. Please post a definition from a good dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spain "*alrededores*" is more used than "*contornos*" (in fact I have never heard it to refer the surrounding areas, it is more used as a geometrical concept).

Other words that are commonly used for that meaning are the following ones:

- El "*extrarradio*" de Barcelona incluye poblaciones como Badalona, L`Hospitalet, . . .
- En las *cercanías*" del pueblo se encuentran las huertas de los propietarios.
- En los *suburbios* de Madrid se puede ver el efecto de la crisis (surrounding areas related with poverty, also it is used *arrabal*).
- He estado en los "*aledaños*" del estadio (more used for the close area of a certain place).

Comment: contornos and alrededores are different and the first does not mean neighborhood  or surroundings of a place.

Comment: Hi @Lambie! The first acceptation of "contorno" says "Territorio o conjunto de parajes de que está rodeado un lugar o una población" [https://www.rae.es/drae2001/contorno]